# How to Keep ViewModel Constructor From Being Called Twice

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, avaloniaui

I'm very new to MVVM and am having an issue with my ViewModel constructor being called twice. In the code below, I'm instantiating a new MainWindowViewModel and assigning it to the MainWindow's DataContext.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        DataContext = mainWindowViewModel; //Set the datacontext to the view model
        this.Opened += mainWindowViewModel.WindowLoaded; //Subscribe to Window Opened Event
       
    }
}
```

I understand that I could have just done something like this:

`DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()`

The thing is I need to be able to subscribe to the MainWindow's "Opened" event and that was the only way I could figure out how to do it. So in the MainWindowViewModel I have this function:

```
 public void WindowLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
        //Do The Stuff When Window is Loaded
     
    }
```

Is there anyway I could keep the MainWindowViewModel constructor from being called twice and still be able to subscribe to the MainWindow event? Any help or nudge in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When your constructor is called twice it means two different instances of your class have been created. If you expect to have just one that's a problem. But your code shows nothing where and why that should happen.

Comment: It looks like it gets called again when I set the DataContext property. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: But then the problem surrounding your question does not exist and you have no question anymore?

Comment: My problem is that i need to do both. The DataContext needs to be set, and I need something to happen in the ViewModel when the Window Opens. Is there a way I can accomplish those two things without the constructor running twice? One when I instantiate the object(gotta do this to subscribe to the event) and two when I set the DataContext.

Comment: I thought we established that the constructor isn't called twice. In your code first you create an instance (constructor called). Then you assign that instance to DataContext (its just an assignment nothing else happens here no constructor called) and then you assign the WindowLoaded method of your ViewModel to the Windows Event (never heart of an Opened Event by the way but is presumably something from Avalonia you tagged). But also no constructor call just an assignment. Your code in the MainWindow  s constructor looks perfectly valid. So again what is the actual problem?

Comment: Sorry, I figured out what was wrong. There was some code in my App.xaml.cs file that was assigning the DataContext as well. I removed that, and it no longer happens now. Thank you!